# How to set Promotion cart rules that customer can use only one Rule

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

my question :

How to set up cart rules that customer can use only one Promotion .

example

Today we offer free shipping ( without coupon ) but in promtion rule .
customer have also coupon 5% discount)

so today automatic Free shipping , but customer insert coupon code and get two promotions two discounts !

what we want is . if customer insert coupon code so the other promotion is lost .

any suggestion .?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set customer coupon code priority high.
2. Set **Stop Further Rules Processing** to **Yes**.
3. You can find this option in shopping cart price rule under **Action Tab**.